# jest mocking a typescript import as dependency

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I searched quite a bit for this and the solutions I see seem a bit hacky and not straightforward for what I think should be a fairly straightforward task.

I have the following class

```
// client.ts
export interface myClient {
  getClient: (customerId: string) => Promise<string>;
}

const impClient = (): myClient => {   

  return {
    getClient: async (customerId: string) => {
     // Implementation
    }
  };
};

export default impClient;
```

I'm trying to mock this in jest with a default implementation.  I tried many approaches including

```
 jest.mock('./client', () =>
    jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return () => {
        return {
          getClient: () => {
            return Promise.resolve('abcde');
          }
        };
      };
    })
  );
```

but none of them seem to work.  Can someone please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`client.ts`:

```js
export interface myClient {
  getClient: (customerId: string) => Promise<string>;
}

const impClient = (): myClient => {
  return {
    getClient: async (customerId: string) => {
      return customerId;
    }
  };
};

export default impClient;
```

`main.ts`, the `main` function use `impClient`

```js
import impClient from './client';

export function main(customerId) {
  return impClient().getClient(customerId);
}
```

`main.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './main';
import impClient from './client';

jest.mock('./client.ts', () => {
  const mockedClient = {
    getClient: jest.fn()
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mockedClient);
});

const client = impClient();

describe('main', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should return client correctly', async () => {
    (client.getClient as jest.MockedFunction<typeof client.getClient>).mockResolvedValueOnce('abcde');
    const customerId = '1';
    const actualValue = await main(customerId);
    expect(actualValue).toBe('abcde');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58107885/main.spec.ts (9.342s)
  main
    ✓ should return client correctly (4ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 main.ts  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.052s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58107885

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately there is no method called . `jest.MockedFunction`

Comment: @tmpdev It's not a method, it's an interface. Because the demo is wroten by typescript. If you use javascript, you can ignore it.

Comment: what I'm trying to get at is `MockedFunction` does not exist.  Plus is there any way to reset just the mock only instead of all the mocks.